# How to build sunken shed foundation with insulation

Tags: insulation, foundation, shed

I'm planning to build a garden office shed about 2.5m wide by 3m long. Regulations in the UK mean I cannot exceed 2.5m high since it will be close to the boundary of my property. The picture below shows a rough idea of the front elevation. I want to use a pitched roof and so it's actually quite tight to make the roof high enough for the door (just over 1.9m).

[image: Garden office front elevation]

I've researched insulation regulations (I don't *have* to stick to these, as it's just a shed, but I do want to make it warm as I will be working there year-round). To achieve the recommended level of insulation, it looks like I would need around 150mm of PIR insulation board. The obvious thing would be to pour concrete foundation blocks and attach a wooden frame to this before inserting the insulation. Something like the picture below:

[image: Shed foundation]

The problem is that this would be sitting just above ground level and would thus take away a valuable 150mm from my available headroom. What sort of foundation could I build which would leave the floor level only just above ground level, while also providing decent insulation?

Comment: Looks like you can exceed the 2.5m limit, that's just the point where you need permission from your local authorities. If you're just exceeding the limits by a few inches, I assume you could get that permission without too much trouble.

Comment: Insulated Concrete Forms (ICFs) might be something to look into.

Comment: @Charles those look to be more related to walls than foundations unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: You can also purchase insulated CMUs (cement blocks) rather than forms.

Answer (score 2):

Change your roof style! It is a shed why have a high pitch? A almost totally flat roof with a membrane surface will do what you want , these hold up well even in costal areas where I live on the other side of the pond, and in some areas even a 1/2 inch two tall ends up in legal issues , a almost flat membrane was the way to do it , it holds up well drains even heavy rainfalls and they can last a long time if properly installed, want to go a bit cheaper rolled roofing that is heat sealed , not as good as membrane but much cheaper. I agree icf are blocks for walls not foundations, high density foam under a slab is a cost effective way to insulate and add a hydronic heating system and it could be quite nice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to go with a pitched roof to be more in keeping with the style of the house and neighbouring houses.